Disable previous dates and all Saturdays and Sundays in Datepicker
I want to disable previous dates and all Saturdays and Sundays in Datepicker. How can I do that?
<input class="col-lg-3" type="date" min="{{ minimumDate}}" id="form3Example1cg" placeholder="Date" formControlName="date" class="form-control form-control-lg" />

minimumDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];


To disable all previous dates, set the [min] attribute to the current date, and to disable the weekends, you can use [attr.disabled] and check if the day of the date is Sunday or Monday
<input class="col-lg-3 form-control form-control-lg" 
       type="date" 
       [min]="currentDate" 
       [attr.disabled]="isWeekend(date) ? '' : null"
       id="form3Example1cg" 
       placeholder="Date" 
       formControlName="date">

Define the isWeekend function.
  isWeekend(date: Date): boolean {
    const day = date.getDay();
    return day === 0 || day === 6; // 0 = Sunday, 6 = Saturday
  }


Cannot seem to get this solution to work, could you post a working snippet or fiddle?
